# What code did 37Signals use for their home page hover effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The hover button effects on http://37signals.com/ are beautiful and super quick.  How did they do it?  It appears to be javascript and css3, but I can't tell, from the source code, what kind of functions they used to achieve the effect.

Thanks!
Azeem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a few divs (with classes `box hover_container hover_target`) that have a hover event attached to it. When the user hovers over a target box, the class `hover` is added to it. The class `hover` has a gradient effect which highlights the currently hovered block.

Each of those blocks have a custom arrow image and text associated with it inside the markup. It's simple enough to see which one is being hovered over and display the correct content and arrows

Comment: this "Hover Observer" function they use is interesting, and not public. Closest thing I could find: http://artchang.com/javascript-closures-0

Comment: you could easily do something like that with jquery's .hover() method though